# Capybara is unable to find a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I have the following form

```
<%= form_for(@route, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal", :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="route_origin_input" id="route_origin_input" placeholder="From" onFocus="geolocate(); autocompleteLocation(this,route_origin)" class="form-control" />
    <%= f.hidden_field :origin, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="route_destination_input" id="route_destination_input" placeholder="Destination" onFocus="geolocate(); autocompleteLocation(this,route_destination)" class="form-control" />
    <%= f.hidden_field :destination, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicleList, 'vehicle', 'vehicle') %>
   <%= f.select :vehicle,  options, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.date_field :departure_date, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", id: "route_post" %>
<% end %>
```

and the following test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Route pages" do

subject { page }

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }

describe "route creation" do
    before { 
        visit terminal_path 
    }

    describe "with invalid information" do

        it "should not create a route" do
            expect { click_button "route_post" }.not_to change(Route, :count)
        end

        describe "error messages" do
            before { click_button "route_post" }
            it { should have_danger_message('Not Submitted') }
        end

    end

    describe "with valid information", :js => true do 

        before do
            fill_in 'route_origin_input', with: "Kimmage, Dublin, Ireland"

            fill_in 'route_destination_input', with: "Kimmage, Dublin, Ireland"

            fill_in 'route_departure_date', with: Time.now
            select 'Car', :from => "route_vehicle"
        end

        it "should create a route" do
            expect { click_button "route_post" }.to change(Route, :count).by(1)
        end

    end
end
end
```

For some reason the two text fields that I have added with html cannot be found by capybara

The error I receive is

> Failure/Error: fill_in 'route_origin_input', with: "Kimmage, Dublin,
>   Ireland"
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find field "route_origin_input"
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in
>   `block in find'
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in`
>   synchronize'
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:30:in
>   `find'
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:56:in`
>   fill_in'
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:676:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
>        # /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>        # ./spec/requests/route_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (4 levels) in '

I've used fill_in in other tests and the only difference I can see is that I have used standard html code in the form. These fields are used to process the info the user enters and then add the result to a hidden field that is part of my model, basically getting the result from Google maps api.

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="route_origin_input" id="route_origin_input" placeholder="From" onFocus="geolocate(); autocompleteLocation(this,route_origin)" class="form-control" />
    <input class="form-control" id="route_origin" name="route[origin]" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: try page.find(:fillable_field, 'route_origin_date').set "Kimmage, Dublin, Ireland"

Comment: ...or you might not need to the 'page.' prefix on that line. I can't remember for certain.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: @BSeven that is added now

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and spec look OK. Here's some things I would try:

1. Are you sure it is failing on `route_origin_input` and not another field?
2. What if you run it without `:js => true`? Perhaps there is some Javascript that is preventing the form from rendering or redirecting.
3. Use save_and_open_page and/or get a screenshot to see what is going on.
4. Which driver are you using? Different drivers behave differently. Try a different driver.
5. Try `selenium-webdriver`. It runs a browser and you can see what is going on. Use `sleep 10` before the `fill_in`. The spec will pause and you can inspect the form or manually fill it in.
6. Usually I use `within '.form' do`. That may make a difference. See [Capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for how to use `within`.

Comment: 1. Either route_origin_input or route_destination_input cause the error depending on the order their executed. 2. :js => true allows capybara to find the input field, but the input is used by the js to populate a hidden field that is part of my model. 3,4. I'm using capybara-webkit so not sure a screenshot would work. 5. I was using selenium-webdriver but I moved to capybara because I needed to run js. 6. I'll look at within form

Comment: there seems to be an issue with my signin helper in my test. It seems to work for other tests but not this one for some reason.